# Inserting spaces between elements with paste0()-function in R

Tags: r, paste

I am solving a task for my online R course. I have the following vector:

```
L<-list(Surname=c("Javi","James","Thomas","Arjen","David","Arturo","Robert"),
        Number=c(8,11,25,10,27,23,9),
        Name=c("Martinez","Rodriguez","Mueller","Robben","Alaba","Vidal","Lewandowski")
```

The task is to output the following result using the paste0()-function:

```
[1] "8:Javi Martinez" "11:James Rodriguez" "25:Thomas Müller"
[4] "10:Arjen Robben" ...
```

Using the function:

```
paste0(L$Nummer,L$Vorname,L$Name)
```

results in:

```
[1] "8JaviMartinez"      "11JamesRodriguez"   "25ThomasMueller"  
[4] "10ArjenRobben"
```

I've tried to use the sep and the collapse arguments, but both of them only affect the end of the elements, for example 8JaviMartinez-, when using sep="-".

Comment: Use `paste` and not `paste0`. There you can specify sep and collapse. Or write `paste0(L$Nummer, " ", L$Vorname, " ", L$Name)`

Comment: @Kath is correct. `paste0` is a shortcut for `paste(x, sep="")`

Comment: `paste0` literally doesn't use a seperator. So try something else

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, I am assuming there is no space before and after colon(:), With the restriction of not using `paste`, you can choose `paste0` with spaces in between.

```
paste0(L$Number,":",L$Surname," ",L$Name)
```

However, I am not sure, If there are any further restrictions that are there to solve this problem.

**Output:**

```
> paste0(L$Number,":",L$Surname," ",L$Name)
[1] "8:Javi Martinez"      "11:James Rodriguez"  
[3] "25:Thomas Mueller"    "10:Arjen Robben"     
[5] "27:David Alaba"       "23:Arturo Vidal"     
[7] "9:Robert Lewandowski"
```